Why is this error showing up when I run this section with a list in it?
I put a list in the section title of my document. Here is the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\section{My Controversial Opinions: 
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
      \item  Taylor Swift is overrated
      \item  Wiping your posterior with toilet paper is gross
      \item  Legend of Korra is not that bad.
\end{enumerate}
}
\subsection{\schemestart
\chemfig{Na_2SO_4}
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{H_2O}]}
\chemfig{Na^+}\+\chemfig{SO_2^{-}}
\schemestop
}
    \end{document}

I know it feels like the list should not be in the section title but I want it that way. Each time I run the code on Overleaf, I get the following error messages: Argument of @sect has an extra } , Runaway argument? and others. I checked the syntax several times and it doesn't seem wrong. Also, I added the chemistry equation because it is important for the actual document and that is when the code becomes unable to be run. There are errors without the Chemistry code but I can still run it on overleaf.

IMO, you mis-use \section (badly).

@JeT Is there a way to fix the section code while keeping the list in the title?

Very bad idea, the list in the section title, anyway…
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newsavebox{\sectionbox}
\newlength{\sectionwd}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\sectionbox}
\addtocounter{section}{1}%
\Large\bfseries\settowidth{\sectionwd}{\thesection\quad}%
\addtocounter{section}{-1}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{\textwidth-\sectionwd}}
My Controversial Opinions: 
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
      \item  Taylor Swift is overrated
      \item  Wiping your posterior with toilet paper is gross
      \item  Legend of Korra is not that bad.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
\section{\usebox{\sectionbox}}

\begin{lrbox}{\sectionbox}
\large\bfseries
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}%
\schemestart
\chemfig{Na_2SO_4}
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{H_2O}]}
\chemfig{Na^+}\+\chemfig{SO_2^{-}}
\schemestop
\end{lrbox}
\subsection{\usebox{\sectionbox}}

\end{document}


I'd recommend enumitem over enumerate.

I will take heed of the advice from you and @JeT and shorten the section title but say for some odd reason, I had a footnote in the section title and the list was still in the section. What should I do? Because with this code, the section appears in the box.

You misuse section.
Stick to a simple assignment of objects in your code.
Maybe as simple as that ?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\section{My Controversial Opinions}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Taylor Swift is overrated
    \item Wiping your posterior with toilet paper is gross
    \item Legend of Korra is not that bad.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Chemical Equation Example}
\schemestart
\chemfig{Na_2SO_4}
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{H_2O}]}
\chemfig{Na^+}\+\chemfig{SO_2^{-}}
\schemestop

\end{document}

NB : I am not responsible for the text of the list....

I can concede the section but I wish the subsection to just be the equation.

@Vector so you don't want the subsection to have a number, but the keep the text ?

I don't mind if it has a number but I want the subsection title to be the equation. Also, with regard to the text, the original document has something confidential and instead of just writing text or sample text, I wanted to have some fun....and I may or may not believe two of the things  I wrote down. :) No one will ever know.
